# Why does the Spyder debugger seem totally unresponsive?

Tags: debugging, spyder

I'm new to trying out Spyder, and attempting to debug. I'm very familiar with Matlab's debugging, which Spyder's appears similar to.

Unfortunately, when I enter debug mode, the debug menu buttons and hotkeys are unresponsive; nothing happens when I click or type them. I have no idea where to start to resolve this. I can start the debugger, which opens the ipdb console, without issue. But then it's totally unresponsive to anything other than literally typing into the ipdb console (e.g., 'quit', or define variables [which does work])

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is there followup information that could be helpful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case this is useful to anyone in the future, this was solved with a full un-install / re-install of anaconda. I don't know what the original problem was.

Comment: You should add that as an answer. I'm sure it's going to be helpful to other people.

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks so much for all your work on Spyder! :D :D :D

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you find Spyder useful for your work.

Comment: Is this a bug? I am not using Anaconda, just Spyder directly. I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone in the future, this was solved with a full un-install / re-install of anaconda. I don't know what the original problem was.